# More GWT and Tomcat 6 Security headaches (windows)

Tags: security, tomcat, gwt, rpc

Hey guys, I've been browsing around on SO for quite some time and can't thank everyone enough.

I've finally come to a road block after ironing out the other bugs in my code:  Tomcat 6's security manager combined with Java's security is stalling me.  Basically, I've written a web application (that only trusted people will have access to, so I don't need the security lecture here :-D) that needs to access a local filesystem after it's done some parsing to locate directories.

After tons of google-kung-fu and all of the " and + searching in the world, I can't find how to turn off Tomcat 6's security manager in Windows, or how to effectively neutralize it combined with forcing it to start.  Using "-security" in the config gui doesn't work and I've tried adding commas and newlines to separate it from the lone "start" that's there currently.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/124004/tomcat-6-access-control-exception/126888#126888

Comment: Also might be relevant to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645298/how-to-sanely-configure-security-policy-in-tomcat-6

Comment: I've been to both of those :-)

I'm just not sure how it translates from ubuntu back to windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to turning it off, I learned another mistake I was making:  forgetting to include the default constructor (with no parameters) for one of my serialized classes.  Remember to check GWT's (somewhat quirky) rules for serialization!

I've since gone back and turned the tomcat security back on, only giving my specific application to the resources it needs.