# Call a shell script in java?

Tags: java, bash, shell, webcam

is it possible to call a **shellscript** or the shellcode in a **java** class?

My Code (in a static method):

```
Runtime rtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process child = rtime.exec("/bin/bash");
BufferedWriter outCommand = new BufferedWriter(new
OutputStreamWriter(child.getOutputStream()));
outCommand.write("streamer -c /dev/video0 -b32 -o test.jpeg");
outCommand.flush();
outCommand.close();
child.destroy();
```

But I get this error, if i try this code in my jsp page (tomcat6):

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission /bin/bash execute)

Any solution for this problem?

**EDIT**:
ls -l /bin/bash shows me follwing line:

*-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 875596 2009-09-14 07:09 /bin/bash*

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a packaged version of Tomcat? If yes, it comes with very restrictive permissions.

Comment: Hmm.. dont know just downloaded apt-get install tomcat6

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the security manager running, and you may have good reasons for doing so, then you can simply change the policy file that Tomcat is using.  The files may be located in `/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/policy.d`.

[A nice SO thread discusses this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645298/how-to-sanely-configure-security-policy-in-tomcat-6) already.  Even if you grant `AllPermissions` to your application, running with the `SecurityManager` will allow you to use sandboxes with limited security.  You might want to do that, say, to run JavaScript that could be uploaded at runtime or something similar, or there may be some other code in your application that you don't trust for some reason.

Comment: I mean "sandboxes with limited permissions."

Comment: And if there is more than one web-app running, you perhaps do not want them all to have free reign.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable the security manager. Edit `/etc/init.d/tomcat6` and change:

```
TOMCAT_SECURITY=yes
```

Change that to:

```
TOMCAT_SECURITY=no
```

And then restart Tomcat:

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart
```

If it works, it's up to you to see if fully disabling the security manager is acceptable or not (using it is actually unusual IMO).

Answer (score 1):

Also if possible, attempt to run it in the single exec call.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
```

where args is a string array of arguments.

```
String[] args = new String[] {"/bin/bash", "streamer", "-c", "/dev/video0", "-b32", "-o", "test.jpeg" };
```

Comment: Yes, passing the args as individual strings is highly recommended, especially if any of them could be changed by a user who might try to do some shell code injection.